# how to validate enter button?

Tags: asp.net

i had a functionality that in text box after entering a value when i pressed enter the value was validated.
Now i wanted to perform similar task by using enter button.
I had created an event for button click but not able to understand how to perform enter action.

i am sending code:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnCancel" Content="CANCEL" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle10}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="PlayerSwipeBtn_Click" Width="110" Height="55"  Margin="303,6,113,4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                <Button x:Name="BtnEntername" Content="Enter" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle10}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="110" Height="55"  Margin="113,6,303,4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="BtnEntername_Click" />

Xaml.cs code:
private void PlayerSwipeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnAction = (Button)sender;
            ACTION = btnAction.Tag.ToString();
            if (ACTION == PLAYER_ACTIONS_CODE.CANCEL)
                this.DialogResult = false;
            else
                this.DialogResult = true;
        }
```

what to do for enter button to validate entry.

Comment: which platform you are working?

Comment: What do you mean by trying to "validate Enter Button"?

Comment: means when i press enter button the entry is validated.But,now i want to do the same on adding a button "enter" and then clicking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below might help you. KeyCode for enter key is "13", you can modify and perform your logic to the below code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function clickButton(e)
         {          
            var bt = document.getElementById('buttonid');           
            if (typeof bt == 'object')
            { 
                if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape")>(-1))
                { 
                    if (e.keyCode == 13)
                    { 
                           //Enter Key Pressed
                            return false; 
                    } 
                } 
                if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet Explorer")>(-1))
                { 
                    if (event.keyCode == 13)
                    { 
                           //Enter Key Pressed
                            return false; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
         }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below might help you out.

```
SearcbTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById('" + CancelButton.UniqueID + "').click();return false;}} else {return true}; ");
```